# directive does not work in the ons-toolbar

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I use Angularjs and OnsenUI and define a directive like this:

```
 module.directive('selectDIY',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: "<select class=\"portNameList\" id=\"portfoliosId\"  ng-change=\"selectedPortfolioChanged( $index)\">"
                +"<option ng-repeat=\"portfolio in portfoliosPriceList track by $index\" value=\"{{portfolio.id}}\" >"
                +"{{portfolio.portname}}</option> </select>"
}
```

})

In the html like this:

```
 <ons-page ng-controller="portfoliosController">
    <ons-toolbar class="DCF"  fixed-style>
        <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >
           <selectDIY></selectDIY>
        </div>
        <div class="right" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('createPortName.html',  { animation : 'slide'});" style="font-size:22px;color:white;padding-right:10px;margin-top:12px;" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
    </ons-toolbar>
```

Anybody knows how to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your directive `selectDIY`, you must refer to it by `<select-d-i-y>`, for example, in the DOM.

Or, if you want to refer to it by `<selectDIY>` in the DOM, you must define it as following. `module.directive('selectdiy',function(){});`

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> - Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> - Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to `camelCase`.

Comment: I believe in this case it would be best to do `module.directive('selectDiy', function() {});` in order to be able to write `<select-diy>` in the templates.